# OracleDataReader - Handling a NULL field value when setting up a default dropdown SelectedValue

Tags: c#, oracle, ado.net

I've got the following code:

```
  // Here is where we will read in all our values and populate the form with them
  lblBenCatX.Text = Convert.ToString(reader["Category"]);
  lblBenProvX.Text = Convert.ToString(reader["Provision"]);
  txtCommentBox.Text = Convert.ToString(reader["Feedback"]);

  ddlDefect1.SelectedValue = Convert.ToString(reader["Network"]);
  ddlIssue1.SelectedValue = Convert.ToString(reader["Issue_ID"]);
  ddlResolution1.SelectedValue = Convert.ToString(reader["Resolution_ID"]);
  ddlDefect2.SelectedValue = Convert.ToString(reader["Network2"]);
  ddlIssue2.SelectedValue = Convert.ToString(reader["Issue_ID2"]);
  ddlResolution2.SelectedValue = Convert.ToString(reader["Resolution_ID2"]);
```

The first 3 rows of code; no problem.  However, if I have a record with a NULL value, the dropdowns break the code.  So, I'm thinking I need to check the field first to make sure it's not NULL.  Something like:

```
if (!Convert.ToString(reader["Network"]) = NULL)
{
  ddlDefect1.SelectedValue = Convert.ToString(reader["Network"]);
}
```

However, that's giving me an error:

> The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or
>   indexer

Any ideas?  This is C# in VS2015 with an Oracle back end, if any of that matters.

Comment: Hey man, I was checking out your profile.  Just wanted to let you know both your links are broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C#, you need to use two equal signs in a row `==` for equality comparison, not one.  One equal sign `=` is an assignment operator.

```
if (first == second) { ... }
```

In your case, though, you would want to use the "not equals" `!=` operator:

```
if (Convert.ToString(reader["Network"]) != null)
```

Which is cleaner and slightly more-efficent than this:

```
if (!(Convert.ToString(reader["Network"]) == null))
```

Note that I've wrapped the whole inner comparison in parens so the whole statement is being negated; otherwise, it will think you're trying to say `!Convert.ToString(reader["Network"])`, and, as you pointed out in the comments here, you can't use `!` with a string.

That being said, if you're converting to string, then it's better to use `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` for checking:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(reader["Network"].ToString())))
```

But the best is probably to just check if the column value is null, rather than converting it to string:

```
if (!reader.IsDBNull(["Network"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

`=` is an assignment operator, used when setting values.

`==` is an equality operator, which determines whether something is equal to something else.

`!=` is also an equality operator, opposite to the one above. So, when something is **not** equal to something else.

So actually, you should be using `!=` in this scenario:

```
if (Convert.ToString(reader["Network"]) != null)
{
  ddlDefect1.SelectedValue = Convert.ToString(reader["Network"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of choices. The first is to check if the value is `DBNull` which is different than an empty string/null value.

```
if (!reader.IsDBNull([ordinalPositionOfNetworkInSelectStatement]))
   ddlDefect1.SelectedValue = Convert.ToString(reader["Network"]);
```

See [IDataReader.IsDBNull](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatarecord.isdbnull(v=vs.110).aspx). The only thing is that you need to know the ordinal position of the column you are checking.

---

The alternative is to check for dbnull in your sql select statement and use a function to return an empty string if it is. The positive side of this approach is you do not have to worry about checking for `null` in your c# code but I am not sure if it has any negative consequences in your oracle query or view. You can do this with `COALESCE`.

```
SELECT Category, Provision, Feedback, COALESCE(Network, '') AS Network /*other columns*/ 
FROM ... -- rest of the query
```

*disclaimer - my oracle syntax is lacking but COALESCE does exist as a function*